# Rendering axios response in React Bootstrap Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-bootstrap-table

Sorry, I know this is a newbie question, but I'm hoping someone can help.

I'm learning React and have a component `todos-list.component.js` which shows the results of an axios request and renders in a table and all is good (apart from some style issues which I'm not fussed about at the moment):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const Todo = (props) => (
  <tr>
    <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? "completed" : ""}>
      {props.todo.todo_description}
    </td>
    <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? "completed" : ""}>
      {props.todo.todo_responsible}
    </td>
    <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? "completed" : ""}>
      {props.todo.todo_priority}
    </td>
    <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? "completed" : ""}>
      {props.todo.todo_cardnumber}
    </td>
    <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? "completed" : ""}>
      {props.todo.todo_playername}
    </td>
    <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? "completed" : ""}>
      {props.todo.todo_teamname}
    </td>
    <td>
      <Link to={"/edit/" + props.todo._id}>Edit</Link>
    </td>
  </tr>
);

export default class TodosList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { todos: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://webhooks.mongodb-realm.com/api/client/v2.0/app/todo-psiro/service/ToDo/incoming_webhook/todos"
      )
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ todos: response.data });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://webhooks.mongodb-realm.com/api/client/v2.0/app/todo-psiro/service/ToDo/incoming_webhook/todos"
      )
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ todos: response.data });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  todoList() {
    return this.state.todos.map(function (currentTodo, i) {
      return <Todo todo={currentTodo} key={i} />;
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Todos List</h3>
        <table className="table table-striped" style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Team Name</th>
              <th>Player Name</th>
              <th>Card Number</th>
              <th>Responsible</th>
              <th>Priority</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{this.todoList()}</tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I then have a different component `table.component.js` which renders static data into a React Bootstrap Table (https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/) and again this works fine:

```
import BootstrapTable from "react-bootstrap-table-next";
import paginationFactory from "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const data = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "banana",
    price: "0.25",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "spinach",
    price: "4.49",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "icecream",
    price: "4.99",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "bagel",
    price: "1.19",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "fish",
    price: "10.00",
  },
];

const columns = [
  {
    dataField: "id",
    hidden: true,
  },
  {
    dataField: "name",
    text: "Grocery",
    sort: true,
  },
  {
    dataField: "price",
    text: "Price",
    formatter: (cell, row) => {
      return <p>${cell}</p>;
    },
    sort: true,
    sortFunc: (a, b, order, dataField, rowA, rowB) => {
      const numA = parseFloat(a);
      const numB = parseFloat(b);
      if (order === "asc") {
        return numB - numA;
      }
      return numA - numB; // desc
    },
  },
];

const BasicTable = () => {
  return (
    <BootstrapTable
      keyField="id"
      data={data}
      columns={columns}
      striped
      hover
      condensed
      pagination={paginationFactory({})}
    />
  );
};

export default BasicTable;
```

However what I would like to do is combine these so that the results of the axios GET request get rendered through the React Bootstrap Table.  Can anyone help?

Comment: what's the purpose of showing this component `todos-list.component.js`?

Comment: Hi. It's just to show (in table format) all of the to do items

Comment: Okay. Are you trying to show todos via an api in your table?

Comment: yes, the api call is in the first code block - eg         "https://webhooks.mongodb-realm.com/api/client/v2.0/app/todo-psiro/service/ToDo/incoming_webhook/todos"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using a Function Component as the React ecysystem is moving towards that approach.

You can use the `useState` hook to manage the state and the `useEffect` hook to make the API call.

Something like this:

```
import BootstrapTable from "react-bootstrap-table-next";
import paginationFactory from "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator";
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from "react";
import {
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const columns = [{
    dataField: "_id",
    hidden: true
  },
  {
    dataField: "todo_description",
    text: "Description",
    sort: true
  },
  {
    dataField: "todo_teamname",
    text: "Team Name",
    sort: true
  },
  {
    dataField: "todo_playername",
    text: "Player Name",
    sort: true
  },
  {
    dataField: "todo_cardnumber",
    text: "Card Number",
    sort: true
  },
  {
    dataField: "todo_responsible",
    text: "Responsible",
    sort: true
  },
  {
    dataField: "todo_priority",
    text: "Priority",
    sort: true
  },
  {
    dataField: "action",
    text: "Action"
  }
];

const TableWithData = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://webhooks.mongodb-realm.com/api/client/v2.0/app/todo-psiro/service/ToDo/incoming_webhook/todos"
      )
      .then(response => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return ( <
    BootstrapTable keyField = "id"
    data = {
      data
    }
    columns = {
      columns
    }
    striped hover condensed pagination = {
      paginationFactory()
    }
    />
  );
};

export default TableWithData;
```

Take a look at the `TableWithData` Component.

> Here's a **[Working Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bootstrap-table-with-data-eg?file=src/TableWithData.js)** for your ref.

Comment: many thanks for this.  Do you happen to know how I might do about making some of the items in that table a link (grabbing values from props available on `RowPureContent`)? I'd like to be able to link off to a page (manchester for example) when the teamname value is manchester

Answer (score 1):

1. Do your `apiCall` in your componentDidMount
2. Only show the table when the data has arrived.
3. Map your key of todo object to the dataField in the columns.

You could check the working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rxwqte?file=src%2FApp.js)

```
import BootstrapTable from "react-bootstrap-table-next";
import paginationFactory from "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";


const columns = [
  {
    dataField: "todo_id",
    text: "id",
  },
  {
    dataField: "todo_description",
    text: "description",
    sort: true,
  },
   {
    dataField: "todo_priority",
    text: "priority",
    sort: true,
  },
];

const url = 'https://webhooks.mongodb-realm.com/api/client/v2.0/app/todo-psiro/service/ToDo/incoming_webhook/todos'

class BasicTable extends React.Component {
  state = { data: null };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { data } = await axios.get(url)
    this.setState({ data });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.data) return null;
    console.log(this.state.data);
    
    return (
      <BootstrapTable
        keyField="id"
        data={this.state.data}
        columns={columns}
        striped
        hover
        condensed
        // pagination={paginationFactory({})}
      />
    ) 
  }
}


export default BasicTable;
```

Comment: thanks, will check this out and get back to you asap